# How to split an array in javascript conditionally

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
activeTickets = [{id:1,assigned_to:null},{id:2,assigned_to:'john'}]
```

I wish to split it to 2 different arrays:

```
activeassignedtickets = [{id:2,assigned_to:john}]

activeunassignedtickets = [{id:1,assigned_to:null}]
```

Comment: what is the condition? what have you tried?

Comment: I tried using 2 maps but found that i would be iterating through twice , i also tried thought of using the append to append it to a new array , but feels that there is a better solution. The condition is to check if assigned is null

Comment: Loop through the array and based on the condition, push them to 2 different arrays

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to want to do one loop, you can consider using `.reduce()` with an accumulator which starts off as an array storing two empty arrays. Based on the number result of `o.assigned_to === null` you can decide which index to put the object into:

```js
const tickets = [{id:1,assigned_to:null},{id:2,assigned_to:'john'}];

const [activeTickets, unassignedTickets] = tickets.reduce(
  (arr, o) => (arr[+(o.assigned_to === null)].push(o), arr), 
[[], []]);

console.log(unassignedTickets);
console.log(activeTickets);
```

You can simplify this to be just a loop though, which in my opinion is easier to understand and read. Here we're looping over each object in the array and checking the value of the `assigned_to` property. If `assigned_to` is null you can add it to the unassigned list, otherwise, if it isn't null, you can add it to the active list:

```js
const tickets = [{id:1,assigned_to:null},{id:2,assigned_to:'john'}];

const activeTickets = [];
const unassignedTickets = [];
for(let o of tickets) {
  if(o.assigned_to === null)
    unassignedTickets.push(o);
  else
    activeTickets.push(o);
}

console.log(unassignedTickets);
console.log(activeTickets);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` method to achieve this I believe.

```
const activeTickets = tickets.filter(ticket => ticket.assigned_to !== null)
const unassignedTickets = tickets.filter(ticket => ticket.assigned_to === null)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to create a new constant based on the onces that failed the filter? Because that would mean im iterating through the array less

Comment: @neowenshun, I don't really follow what you mean? If the condition isn't met, then you get an empty array[].

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tickets = [{id:1,assigned_to:null},{id:2,assigned_to:"john"}]
const activeTickets = []
const unassignedTickets= []

// Iterate only once
for(let item of tickets){
    item.assigned_to? activeTickets.push(item) : unassignedTickets.push(item)
}

console.log(activeTickets) // [{id: 2, assigned_to: "john"}]
console.log(unassignedTickets) // [{id: 1, assigned_to: null}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move the assigned to an array and the not assigned items to another array.

```js
const
    activeTickets = [{ id: 1, assigned_to: null }, { id: 2, assigned_to: 'john' }],
    { true: notAssigned, false: assigned } = activeTickets.reduce(
        (r, o) => (r[o.assigned_to === null].push(o), r),
        { true: [], false: [] }
    );

console.log(assigned);
console.log(notAssigned);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tickets = [
  {id:1,assigned_to:null},
  {id:2,assigned_to:'john'}
]

const activeassignedtickets =[]
const activeunassignedtickets = []

for (let i = 0; i < tickets.length; i += 1) {
  (tickets[i].assigned_to === null)
    ? activeunassignedtickets.push(tickets[i]) 
    : activeassignedtickets.push(tickets[i])
}

console.log(activeassignedtickets, activeunassignedtickets)
```

Answer (score -3):

In your case, you can use [`array.slice`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) method.

So here are details about how to do that.

```
activeassignedtickets = activeTickets.slice(1, 2);
activeunassignedtickets = activeTickets.slice(0, 1);
```