# JUST USING THE FOR LOOP: how to divide an array into 2 arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to turn this array into 2 different arrays. One array should be of names that contain the letter 'o' in them and the second array should be the rest of the names, that do not have 'o'.

I can only use the for loop and the only method I can use is .push().

Given array:

```
var names = ['octavia', 'peter', 'olive', 'ava', 'aiden'];
```

Desire result:

```
var nameO = ['octavia', 'olive'];
var nameNoO = ['peter', 'ava', 'aiden'];
```

This is the code I came up with. Got one of the results for names with 'o', but not without 'o'.

```
var names = ['octavia', 'peter', 'olive', 'ava', 'aiden'];
var namesO = [];
var namesNoO = [];
for(let i in names){
  for(let j in names[i]){
    if(names[i][j] === 'o'){
      namesO.push(names[i]);
    } 
    if(names[i][j] !== 'o'){
    namesNoO.push(names[i])
    }
 }
}
console.log(namesO, namesNoO);
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: `if(names[i][j] !== 'o')` pushes all names that have at least one character different from `o` into the `noO` array. For your approach to work, you have to go through the complete name, and only if no `o` was found, add it to the `noO` array

Comment: or [Dividing an array by filter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731072/dividing-an-array-by-filter-function) or [Split array with condition on element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282343/split-array-with-condition-on-element) or [How to split an array in javascript conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63097838/how-to-split-an-array-in-javascript-conditionally)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use include for condition matching.

```js
   var names = ['octavia', 'peter', 'olive', 'ava', 'aiden'];
   var namesO = [];
   var namesNoO = [];

  for(var i=0, l = names.length; i < l; i++) {
     if(names[i].toLowerCase().includes("o")){
      namesO.push(names[i]);
      }
  if(!names[i].toLowerCase().includes("o")){
      namesNoO.push(names[i]);
    }
    }
     console.log(namesO,namesNoO);
```

Comment: the slowest due `toLowerCase()` and double `includes('o')`. a bad choice

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `.filter` function of an array to filter the items. For each string, you can use `.includes` to check if it includes the letter "o". The `.toLowerCase` function converts the input strings to lowercase before comparing them, making sure this works for both capital and lowercase letters.

```
var names = ['John', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Oliver', 'Sophia'];

var namesWithO = names.filter(name => name.toLowerCase().includes('o'));
var namesWithoutO = names.filter(name => !name.toLowerCase().includes('o'));
```

Or

```
var names = ['John', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Oliver', 'Sophia'];

var namesWithO = [];
var namesWithoutO = [];

names.forEach(name =>
{
   if (name.toLowerCase().includes('o'))
   {
      namesWithO.push(name);
   }
   else
   {
      namesWithoutO.push(name);
   }
});
```

Comment: Literally was just typing out this answer

Comment: `Includes` will check all the text rather than just the first letter.

Comment: Yeah as question mention its about have not start with so includes is correct here

Comment: it's O(n*2), could be O(n)

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev  Strictly speaking there is no absolutely difference between O(n) and O(2n)

Comment: @derpirscher i'm not strong with O notation but looping twice will be slower than once in the most cases i think

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev of course it will. But 1) It's still irrevant for *O(?)* notation, because there is no such thing as a *O(2n)* and constant factors just don't matter. And 2) It's completely irrelevant at the size of these exercises and the level of programming skills of OP. Ie someone who has to ask about such a problem won't be near a problem size where this really matters anytime soon. And at the time, OP is confronted with problem sizes where this begins to matter, they will most probably have the skills to do this properly ...

Comment: @derpirscher neglecting micro/milliseconds in many places leads to silly performance for example even on high-mid smartphones

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev  Again. Someone who has to ask about things on that level is far far away from being able to build something that will run on any other device that their own or their teacher's ... And my initial comment wasn't even about real "speed" at all, but the incorrect use of the *O(n)*  concept .

Comment: @derpirscher i should learn better about O(n), thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should spend some time familiarizing yourself with all of the various functions that are part of the Array prototype.

Saying you want to "split" an array suggests you are looking for [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). However, your example suggests what you really want to do is filter your array. To do that you want to use the [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

```js
const names = ['octavia', 'peter', 'olive', 'ava', 'aiden'];
const withNoO = name => !name.includes('o');
const withO = name => name.includes('o');

const nameO = names.filter(withO);
// ['octavia', 'olive'];

const nameNoO = names.filter(withNoO)
// ['peter', 'ava', 'aiden'];
```

I am using ["arrow functions"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to make the code more compact. This could also be done like this:

```js
function withNoO(name) {
    return !name.includes('o');
}

function withO(name) {
    return name.includes('o');
}

const nameO = names.filter(withO);
// ['octavia', 'olive'];

const nameNoO = names.filter(withNoO)
// ['peter', 'ava', 'aiden'];
```